# The type parameter is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I am trying to implement a trait for types such that the reference to the type is convertible into an iterator with `Item` implementing a specific trait

Specifically, consider the following code:

```rust
struct Arena;

pub trait Scan {
    fn scan(&self, arena: &mut Arena);
}

impl<'a, 'b, Iterable, Item> Scan for Iterable
where
    &'b Iterable: IntoIterator<Item = Item>,
    Item: Scan + 'a,
{
    fn scan(&self, arena: &mut Arena) {
        for item in (&self).into_iter() {
            item.scan(arena);
        }
    }
}
```

([See](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4004c4609d53628a59b7d3a381eeb362) this example in the Playground)

The compiler complains, underlining `Item`:

```
the type parameter `Item` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
unconstrained type parameter
```

I do not really understand for now where am I going in the wrong direction: to me, it looks like if the generic implementation is pretty much constrained by the conditions under `where`. How do I explain the idea to the compiler?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766088/rust-using-a-generic-trait-as-a-trait-parameter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write a generic trait implementation such as

```
impl<'a, 'b, Iterable, Item> Scan for Iterable
```

it is required that all the generic types appear in the definition of the type that implements the trait. In your case `Iterable` is there but `Item` is not.

But you do not really need `Item` to be generic. I think you are adding it just to write a constraint on it. Ideally you want to write something like:

```
impl<'a, 'b, Iterable> Scan for Iterable
where
    &'b Iterable: IntoIterator<Item : Scan + 'a>,
```

Unfortunately that is still an unstable feature [`associated_type_bounds`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/52662).

But fortunately you do not need an associated type bound for that. You can write instead:

```
impl<'a, 'b, Iterable> Scan for Iterable
where
    &'b Iterable: IntoIterator,
    <&'b Iterable as IntoIterator>::Item : Scan + 'a,
```

Now the constraints work but the lifetimes fail!

```
error[E0309]: the parameter type `Iterable` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:27:19
   |
27 |     &'b Iterable: IntoIterator,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the reference type `&'b Iterable` does not outlive the data it points at
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...
   |
23 | impl<'a, 'b, Iterable: 'b> Scan for Iterable
   |                      ++++
```

If you do as the compiler nicely suggests and add `Iterable: 'b` and... now if fails in the implementation of the function itself:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:31:21
   |
23 | impl<'a, 'b, Iterable> Scan for Iterable
   |          -- lifetime `'b` defined here
...
29 |     fn scan(&self, arena: &mut Arena)
   |             - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
30 |     {
31 |         for item in (&self).into_iter() {
   |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'b`
```

Which is actually expected, as the anonymous lifetime of `&self` is unrelated to `'b`, and you cannot change that because you cannot add constraints to the implementation of a function trait.

The obvious solution for this (without having any other code around, maybe it won't work for you) is to implement the trait for `&'b Iterable`. This way `&self` is actually `&&'b Iterable` and all fits together. Moreover, now `Iterable: 'b` is implicit and not needed anymore:

```
impl<'a, 'b, Iterable> Scan for &'b Iterable
where
    &'b Iterable: IntoIterator,
    <&'b Iterable as IntoIterator>::Item : Scan + 'a,
{
    fn scan(&self, arena: &mut Arena)
    {
        for item in self.into_iter() {
            item.scan(arena);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW, as it is I think the `'a` lifetime is mostly useless.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would define this implementation:

```
impl<Iterable> Scan for Iterable
where
    for<'b> &'b Iterable: IntoIterator,
    for<'b> <&'b Iterable as IntoIterator>::Item: Scan,
{
    fn scan(&self, arena: &mut Arena) {
        for item in (&self).into_iter() {
            item.scan(arena);
        }
    }
}
```

The lifetime annotation `'b` is not really relevant for implementing the trait since the trait itself has no generic lifetime bounds nor does the type you're implementing it upon, a simple generic. It is only used for the constraint that `&Iterable` implements `IntoIterator` for any lifetime. Using `for<_>` is called a higher-ranked trait bound.

I also omitted `'a` since it looked to have no utility in your implementation.

Comment: That you, that seems really nice at first sight. Do you also understand why it [stops working](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e4cbccdd530aaa51b2be64fb2e879e57) at the point when you add an additional `impl` for `RefCell`?

For now I do not really see why the constraints would be malformed so we could hit the recursion limit

Comment: Well shoot, looks like my solution runs into this issue: [Why do I get an "overflow evaluating the requirement" error for a simple trait implementation?](/q/66631251/2189130)