# The param "is not constrained," while it is constrained

Tags: rust

I have a struct `Roll<K : Copy + PartialEq, V : Clone, const N : usize>`, then I'm doing this:

```
struct Foo;
impl<K : Copy + PartialEq, V : Clone, const N : usize> Foo {
    type Value = Roll<K, V, N>;
    fn bar(self) {
        let mut x : Self::Value = Roll::new();
        x.insert(1, 1);
    }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
error[E0207]: the type parameter `K` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
 --> src/foo.rs:3:6
  |
3 | impl<K : Copy + PartialEq, V : Clone, const N : usize> Foo {
  |      ^ unconstrained type parameter
```

What does it mean and how to fix?

Comment: Just move this parameter onto a function itself. Generic parameters on the impl block need to be used as parameters to struct itself.

Comment: I have `Value` also, which is part of the struct (just updated the question)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type parameter is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452724/the-type-parameter-is-not-constrained-by-the-impl-trait-self-type-or-predicate)

Comment: It has to be constrained by the trait, self or predicates, none of which apply in your case.

Comment: Associated types in inherent impl blocks isn't even valid rust.

Comment: @cafce25 I'm not sure I follow. Can you please post an answer and elaborate on what is "constrainted by"? My `struct` uses them all three. What's missing? Also, if I remove them from the `impl`, the function won't compile, since it won't have `K, V, N` defined anywhere.

Comment: No `Foo` the self type uses 0 of your type parameters (it's not generic at all). In addition to there being dupes it's quite well explained [by the extra info the compiler gives](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error_codes/E0207.html?highlight=E0207#)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking Rust to generate a `bar` method for every type `K`, `V`, and `N`, without any way to distinguish which `bar` to call. Rust does not allow that. If you did `Foo.bar()`, how would you tell Rust which generic types to use?

If you had `fn bar<K,V,N>()`, you could do `Foo.bar::<K,V,N>()`. If `Foo` were generic, you could do `Foo::<K,V,N>.bar()`. If you were implementing a trait, you could do `<Foo as MyTrait<K,V,N>>.bar()`. But if your `impl` were allowed, you would have no way to tell Rust what types to use.

An associated type like this on a non-trait `impl` block doesn't make much sense. Make `bar` generic and have it operate on `Roll` instead of `Self::Value`.