# How to implement a Visitor with generic type for Deserializer of serde?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to create a [`Visitor`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.Visitor.html) for `Deserialize`:

```
struct Foo;

impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for Foo {
    type Value = Vec<K>;
    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("foo")
    }
    fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> std::result::Result<Self::Value, A::Error> where A: SeqAccess<'de> {
        let mut vec : Self::Value = Vec::new();
        while let Some(data) = seq.next_element()? {
            vec.push(data);
        }
        Ok(vec)
    }
}
```

It compiles if I replace `Vec<K>` with `Vec<u32>` in the fourth line. However, I need this visitor to be generic. With `Vec<K>` it obviously doesn't compile since `K` is not defined. Where and how I should define it?

Comment: `impl<'de, K>` ?

Comment: It doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76014914

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `K` as a generic parameter to your `Foo` visitor to make `K` constrained.

This compiles on the playground:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<K>(PhantomData<K>);

impl<'de, K: Deserialize<'de>> Visitor<'de> for Foo<K> {
    type Value = Vec<K>;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        formatter.write_str("foo")
    }
    
    fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> std::result::Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
    where
        A: SeqAccess<'de>,
    {
        let mut vec: Self::Value = Vec::new();
        while let Some(data) = seq.next_element()? {
            vec.push(data);
        }
        Ok(vec)
    }
}
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=95a6058612473ddc68266c35293ef94f)